# Which one is better - Else if or OR

Tags: if-statement

I just want to know the best approach, advise to beginner,regardless both will work and its just preference,  Which one is better?

```
    if ( myVar >= 31 ){
        echo 'Not Valid';
        }
    else if (myVar <=0 ){
        echo 'Not Valid';
        } 
    else{
        echo 'ok';
        }
```

//OR

```
    if ( myVar >= 31 || myVar <=0){
        echo 'Not Valid';
        }
    else{
        echo 'ok';
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The second form is better, since there is less code duplication.

Comment: Agreed. Duplication leads to headaches. Headaches lead to stress. Stress leads to road rage. Road rage leads to car accidents. Car accidents lead to death. Doing it the first way would just end up killing you.

Answer (score 0):

Each has it's own advantage to me. The second one reduce the code and that is a good thing to do. However in a situation where by you have a lot of comparison to make . i prefer to use the firs one because its easy to debug. Few times i had many problems with misusing '|| and && ' , and this lead to a wrong result often. Imaging if you have a very long comparison and misuses '|| ' in place of '&&'. It sure give headache and takes time to debug sometimes.

However if you use the first one, you know which node to check and where lies the problem. This my idea though the first one is easier to debug in case of error or failure.